# How do I insert an id by using its name instead of its id?

Tags: sql, ms-access

INSERT INTO Location ( address, businessId )
VALUES ([Enter your adress], [Enter the id of your business]);

This is what I have to add a location of a bussiness. However if I want a normal user to add a location, they're not gonna know the bussinessId, but they will know the businessName.

How can I make it so that they put the bussinesName and the id gets inserted instead?

Comment: do you have your businessId and businessName  somewhere in your database?

Comment: of course. I have a bussiness table which has the bussinessName and businessid.

Comment: so as @linodh's answer you must first get the businessid according
businessName then use it int your insert command

Answer (score 1):

if you are having businesid some where in DB then its fairly easy to locate the business id from the business name (passed as arg).

INSERT INTO Location ( address, businessId ) 
select [Enter your adress], businessId
from [BusinessTable] where name=@businessname

Comment: One thing tho. Locationid is a autonumber type and it jumped from 50 to 64. Any way to fix this? Otherwise, superb answer

Comment: `DBCC` does not work for Ms Access! Youy can use an `INSERT` statement with the required seed however.

Answer (score 0):

try to use trigger in this case. so that as a user inserts a name, id automatcally got inserted in the table.

Comment: Can I get an example of this? I'm fairly new with SQL and would love to learn more. Thank you for your answer :)